# What is a cheap way to add wifi

Tags: wireless-networking

I currently have an ADSL Modem/switch that supports two computers. I would like to add a wifi connection so guests can surf as well. What would be the cheapest type device to get the job done? I have a fairly small and open apartment so range is not an issue.

Thanks!

Comment: What's the make and model of your existing device?

Answer (score 1):

1. Replace the existing modem/switch with an ADSL wireless router.
2. Change the existing modem/switch to bridged mode and add a WiFi wireless router.
3. Configure a wireless router as an access point (make sure to disable its DHCP server and don't use its Internet/WAN port) and connect one of its LAN ports to the existing switch.